# replacing all hits by an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, string, replace

So I tried to replace with an array in a string.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < replacableArray.length; i++ )
{
    inputText = inputText.replace( replacableArray[ i ], replacedArray[ i ] );
}
```

It's easy, but when I wanted to replace all with `\g` it detects as a string, not an array. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object:

```
inputText.replace( new RegExp(replacableArray[ i ], "g"), replacedArray[ i ] )
```

`RegExp` is another signature of the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.